# Rails cannot find templates in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've really strange problem. I have working rails application and on one machine tests don't work. The problem is that when running tests rails cannot find application templates like layout file.

I've tried to debug this and ended up in ActionView::PathResolver class and this particular piece of code below:

```
def find_template_paths(query)
  Dir[query].reject { |filename|
    File.directory?(filename) ||
      # deals with case-insensitive file systems.
      !File.fnmatch(query, filename, File::FNM_EXTGLOB)
  }
end
```

It looks like File.fnmatch methods returns different results in test environment. I've render the same action in development and test environment and compare the results from fnmatch method. In test in cannot match filename to query.

I have no idea why is that. This only happens only on one machine. It is OSX Yosemite 10.10.2 (14C2055), rvm 1.26.11 and ruby 2.2.2p95.